# How to open chrome & visit a webpage on iphone simulator using calabash & webdriver?

Tags: watir-webdriver, calabash, calabash-ios

I want to automate a use case in which I have to open chrome on iOS simulator and visit a web page.
I am using calabash, I am able to start the simulator too but dont know how to start the chrome browser and visit a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to launch Safari using Calabash-iOS.

I googled you question and found this post in the Calabash-ios google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/n0MlBgigbvE

The answer from Karl Krukow (one of the guys who developed Calabash) is a no:

> Hi. It is not possible to automate safari using Calabash (or any other tool I know without jail-breaking the device).
>
> You can automated hybrid apps, i.e., native apps that contain web views. If you're looking for a tool for automating mobile browsers take a look at Selenium, and specifically iPhoneDriver.
>
> Regards,
>   - Karl

If it is a viable solution for you to browse to a given page in a webview inside your own app. Then that should be an option.

Best regards
Lasse